# How to send email to specific selection from html form?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

The idea is to make people select from the list and each value can direct the submission to the selected email. I'm a bit confused with how to make it happens. I need your help.

```
<form action="scripts/request.php" class="contact_form form-style-1 light" novalidate="novalidate" id="header-slogan-form-2-form" style="">
 <div class="form-group select-group">
 <select class="form-control" name="posttype">
    <option value="type-of-post" selected="" disabled="">Post Type</option>
    <option value="complaint">Complaint</option>
    <option value="feedback-form">Feedback</option>
    <option value="suggestion-form">Suggestion</option>
</select></div>
<div class="form-group select-group">
<select class="form-control" name="Department"><option value="department-list" selected="" disabled="">Choice of Department</option>
    <option id="acc-mail" value="account-department">Account Department</option>
    <option id="tech-mail" value="technical-email">Technical Department</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text Here" rows="9" name="POSTAREA"></textarea></div>
    <label class="form-group checkbox text-left">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" placeholder="– i agree with terms and condition" name="AGREEMENT">
    <span class="lbl lbl-style">– i Agree</span></label>
<p class="text txt-form text-center">
<a href="#header-slogan-form-2" target="_blank" class="smooth"></a>
<ins>Terms &amp; Condition</ins></p>
    <button type="submit" data-loading-text="•••" data-complete-text="Completed!" data-reset-text="Try again later..." class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-30 btn-lg">
    <span><b>SEND NOW</b><br></span>
</button>
```

**JS**

```
if($_POST['id'] === "header-slogan-form-2-form") {
$mailto = "general@email.com";

if($_POST['id'] === "acc-mail") {
$mailto = "acc@email.com";

if($_POST['id'] === "tech-mail") {
$mailto = "technical@email.com";

$data_array = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$message = "";
foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value->name) && $value->name !== "") {
        $message .= $value->name.': '.$value->value.'<br>';
    }
}

$subject = "New Post Submission";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (RFC)
$eol = "\r\n";

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: $mailto" . $eol;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $mailto" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

// message
$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$body .= "<div>" . $message . "</div>" . $eol . $eol;

foreach( $_FILES as $file) {
    if ( !move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], dirname(__FILE__) . '/../tmp/' . $file['name'] ) ) {
        echo "error upload file: " . $file['name'];
        continue;
    }
    $filename = $file['name'];
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../tmp';
    $file = $path . "/" . $filename;

    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $body .= $content . $eol . $eol;
}

$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

//SEND Mail
if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    print_r( error_get_last() );
}
}
```

I'm just curious how to make this happen. I've tried several script but it doesn't work. I want different email for each selection and sending to only one email per selection.

I hope you guys don't mock at me because I'm a newbie and need some more experience in this.

Answer (score 0):

your variable `$_POST['id']` is not holding `header-slogan-form-2-form`. $_POST variables only hold the name attribute's value. use jQuery to achieve this. You can you AJAX to submit the form with all the data. like so-

```
$('.contact_form).on('submit', function(){
  var that = $(this);
  var yourVariable = that.attr('id').val();
  console.log(yourVariable); //outputs header-slogan-form-2-form to the console

  $.ajax({
    //your ajax code here!
  });
});
```

Or using php, you can do it in this way-

```
switch($_POST['department']){
  case "acc-mail":
    $mailto = "acc@email.com";
    break;
  case "tech-mail":
    $mailto = "technical@email.com";
    break;
  default:
    $mailto = "general@email.com";
}
```

Comment: Hi, im sorry but i don't get it. can you show it on jsfiddle ? Im a bit blur about this. Btw, thanks for your respond !

Comment: use switch statement. It is pretty straight forward.